# Proving equations using implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Im stuck on this question:

If $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=e^{arcsin(\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})}$

Prove that, $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2*\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{(x-y)^3}$
I'm absolutely clueless in this question i have no idea how to do this. I've just blindly tried taking out the double derivative at first but it was too big and also i tried substitution but that does not seem to work as well. I had an idea of trying to integrate the double derivate given but we apparently aren't supposed to use integration in this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to make a fraction bigger, use dfrac instead of frac, it’ll render the fraction in display mode regardless of the context it’s in.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $$\ln(x^2+y^2)=2\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use polar coordinates, and your equation simplifies to $r^2=e^\theta$